# Cross Compile from Ubuntu to BuildRoot

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, cross-compiling, buildroot

I have a QT5 source code on Ubuntu and I want it to be executed on a BuildRoot system. So I thought about cross compiling (I've already done it for this program from Ubuntu to Windows).

I just can't find out which qmake and make application I have to download on my Ubuntu machine to make it works.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a Buildroot build to generate an image for your target system. As part of the build, Buildroot will also provide a cross-compiler, as well as qmake, all prepared to cross-compile applications that will run on your target.

You could for example have a look at the series of blog posts at https://bootlin.com/blog/building-a-linux-system-for-the-stm32mp1-basic-system/, which precisely teaches how to use Buildroot to build an embedded Linux system, and then develop/debug Qt5 applications for the target, cross-compiled for the host machine.